# How do you cast a media via google home voice assistant to chromecast?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I have a video streaming web application like netflix. I am able to cast a media on my webapp to my TV. I would like to use google home to cast the media using its voice assistant. For example: 'Hey Google, play "Get Out" from <"my-weapp-name">'. This should play Get Out on my TV via a chromecast device that is plugged into my TV. 
How do I use google action and/or dialogflow to do this?

Comment: I want to do the same thing. It is a pitty this does not work yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now there is no public API that can be used for casting media through the Google Assistant.

Comment: Hello, Is this possible now?

Comment: There is still no public API.

Comment: Are we there yet?

Comment: Thanks for checking, no.